# SharedPreferences and check if user is logged in

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Is there a way to check SharedPreferences From an other class, and use this method in all activities of the app by calling directly a method ? and how to call that method in every activity?

Comment: I mean creating a class only for SharedPreferences and call it from Activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aI am not sure if this is what you are looking for, there are more ways to do that. But if you write your Shared preferences class like this:

```
public class Prefs {
    private static final String PREFS = "prefs";
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    public Prefs(Context context){

     prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    public void saveMyString(String string) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("key", string).apply(); //The "key" should be stored in a variable in the rel app.
    }

    public String getMyString(Context context, String WidgetId){
        return prefs.getString("key", "");
    }
}
```

Then you get instance of your Prefs in your activity and can just call your methods.